# SQL Server: Key Lookup without Clustered Index

Tags: sql-server, database, indexing, clustered-index, non-clustered-index

I have a table named `Scan` that has just two columns: `id (int)` and `a (char)`.

It starts without any index. So I created a nonclustered index link following

```
CREATE INDEX ix_id ON scan(id ASC)
```

So I ran this select:

```
SELECT id, a
FROM Scan
WHERE id = 1
```

and this is the execution plan:

[image]

Why did I get a Key Lookup (clustered) if my table doesn't have any clustered index?

Comment: Is `id` marked as primary key in your table? If so, SQL Server *automatically* created a clustered index on that column - this is documented default behavior.

Comment: You can't get a key lookup on a clustered index unless you have a clustered index. So either you have a CI or maybe a bug in whatever application is showing you the plan. Those aren't the SSMS icons.

Comment: @marc_s, I dont have any primary key. I created the test database, then just a simple table without keys or constraints. Then I manually added the snon-clustered index.

Comment: Where are you getting this graphical plan?

Comment: @MartinSmith I am using SQL Operations Studio and Docker as server. AS I mentioned above, I have no clustered index. i don't know where this key lookup came from

Comment: Maybe SQL Operations Studio  is showing the wrong icon then.

Comment: found this https://github.com/Microsoft/sqlopsstudio/issues/391, an issue from sql operations studio saying that key lookup are being presented instead of RID lookup. They closed it, I but I have the latest version, and the problem still there. But you are right, is a bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why did I get a Key Lookup (clustered) if my table doesn't have any
>   clustered index?

You didn't. This is presumably a bug in the [html-query-plan](https://github.com/JustinPealing/html-query-plan) library used by SQL Operations Studio.

The same issue is also visible on the Paste The Plan site ([example](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ry5-3_RVf)).

As you know (because you found it!) the bug report [is here](https://github.com/Microsoft/sqlopsstudio/issues/391).

Comment: Thnak you!Now I'm trying to understand why they closed the issue but the problem still there on the latest version, lol

Comment: The open source project looks like it has a relevant commit 23 days ago (Refactor logic for Key Lookup and RID Lookup). https://github.com/JustinPealing/html-query-plan/commit/7721a0f68ff51fc4bf599846c91a65488b0896b6 Maybe it just hasn't made its way to  the shipped product yet.

Answer (score 1):

Leaf nodes of non clustered index contains only the key columns, so anything apart from key column is selected(in your case it is `a`), then it needs to perform a Rid/key lookup to pull the data from heap/clustered index

use covering index to avoid key lookup

```
CREATE INDEX ix_id ON scan(id ASC) include (a)
```

by this way column `a` will also be stored in your index along with key column, so the key lookup will be avoided

Comment: Actually, if the table *were* a heap, the operation in the execution plan would be called "RID lookup" - not "Key Lookup (clustered)"

Comment: But with a table with only two columns, adding a *covering index* to it seems a bit ..... superfluous - don't you think? Agreed - in order cases, that totally makes sense - but here??

Comment: @marc_s I guess OP was trying to show the problem in simplified manner. But if it is just two columns then yeah

Comment: True, I was trying yo simplify the problem. But I don't have any kind of clustered index, shouldn't key Lookup be called only on a clustered index?